# Understanding the proof: Maclean's Planarity Criteria

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Maclane's planarity criteria states that

A graph $G$ is planar if and only if its cycle space has a basis such that each edge of $G$ belongs to at most two elements of it.

I am reading its proof from the book [Combinatorial Problems and Exercises](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821842625) by Lovasz. The proof is given on Page 297-299 as the solution of Problem 5.35.

One component of the proof is given as follows:

> Let $G$ be a graph having circuits $C_1,\dots,C_f$ which
>   constitute a basis of $W_G$. Further suppose that each edge of $G$ is
>   contained in at most two of $C_1,\dots,C_f$ ($W_G$ is the [cycle
>   space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) of $G$). Show that either all blocks of $G$ are single
>   circuits or there are two $C_i$'s, say $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
>   $C_1+C_2$ is a circuit. (Here $C_1+C_2$ refers to the operation in the
>   cycle space.)

The proof proceeds as follows: If $C_1,\dots,C_f$ are the only circuits then these are all the blocks (an exception are $K_2$'s). Now let $K=\sum_{i=1}^r C_i$ be a circuit such that its representation has a minimum number of terms where $C_1\cap C_2\ne\emptyset$. (Clearly at least two circuits $C_i,C_j$ must share an edge for else $K$ cannot be a circuit. Without loss of generality we may take these to be $C_1,C_2$.)

Then the author goes on to show that

> $K\subset C_1+C_2$ --- (2).

I have no problems with this part.

To prove the reverse inclusion (and thereby conclude the proof) the author then proceeds by contradiction. If $e$ is an edge of $C_1+C_2$ there is no loss of generality in assuming that $e\not\in K\cup C_2$. Then as $e$ is ultimately annihilated in $K=\sum_{i=1}^r C_i$ there must be a $C_k$ for $3\le k\le r$ such that $e\in C_k$ so that $C_1\cap C_k$ share an edge. Now by the method previously applied for $C_1,C_2$ one concludes that

> $K\subset C_1+C_k$. --- (3)

This is followed by the statement:

> But (2) and (3) imply that an edge of $K$ not in $C_1$ must belong to
>   both of $C_2$ and $C_k$ and thus it cannot occur in $\sum_{i=1}^r C_i$, a contradiction.

I don't understand this statement. If $f\in K,C_2,C_k$ with $f\not\in C_1$ it is possible to still have $f$ in $\sum_{i=1}^r C_i$ if it occurs in an odd number of $C_i$'s in the sum.

Can someone kindly resolve my doubt and explain this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the assumption that each edge of $G$ is contained in at most two of the basis circuits $C_1, \dotsc, C_f$. So, if an edge is in both $C_2$ and $C_k$ with $k \neq 2$, then it cannot occur in any other summand and so it cannot occur in $K$.